# Enumerating messages in Outlook's Drafts folder generates an error

Tags: macos, applescript, ms-office

I would like to enumerate the messages in Outlook's 'Drafts' folder.

When I run this script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
  set theMessages to every message in the drafts
  --returns 1
  display dialog of (count of theMessages)
  repeat with theMessage in theMessages
    display dialog of the class of theMessage    -- displays 'inm'
    display dialog of the subject of theMessage  -- error here
  end repeat

end tell
```

I get an error that reads `Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t make subject of outgoing message id 15002 into type string.`.

It seems like `theMessage` is the ID of the message, even though its `class` is 'inm' (guessing that this means inbox message).

If I cast `theMessage` to a `Message`:

```
display dialog of the subject of (theMessage as message)
```

I get a different error: `Can’t make «class inm » id 15492 of application "Microsoft Outlook" into type message.`

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax:

```
display dialog of the (subject of theMessage as text)
```